# Selecting Items from multiple choice ListView - android

Tags: android, list, listview, onclick, android-listview

I want to select the items which user checks in the list view. I have set the listview to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and it shows me the list where i can make multiple selections. But how to get the checked items? I tried using : 
        SparseBooleanArray sp= lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
It does well to store the checked items but when any checked item is unchecked, it does not update the array; it shows the previous data where the now unchecked item was checked. 
Is there a way to do it??
Here's my code:

```
    final ListView lv = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,arrayList);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> 
            myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng){

            SparseBooleanArray sp= lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

            String str="";
            for(int i=0;i<sp.size();i++)
            {
                str+=arrayList.get(sp.keyAt(i))+",";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "You selected: "+str,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }                 
    });
```

I also want to remember the checked items and show it as checked when the list is opened.

Comment: IMO

if (sp.valueAt(i))  processCheckedItem(sp.keyAt(i));

Comment: which class does processCheckedItem() belong to? i'm not able to call it as just. Need to call it through an object.

Comment: processCheckedItem is example custom function. You can do whatever. afaik in this case "keyAt" returns (un)checked item position, "valueAt" returns if the item at "keyAt" is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the method notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter.  This will update the SparseBooleanArray.  Right now you check and uncheck items, and the backing data structure has no idea what you are doing.  You can call it through the adapter by adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or you can override a method in the adapter class and call it directly.

Comment: ok i figured out how to do it. Now i want to make the list remember what was selected before and show those items as checked when list is opened. I had stored the previously checked items in a file. How can i make those items checked when list is opened?

Comment: Have a singleton class ListManager which keeps track of the list items, pulls in the checked list items and positions from the file, update the singleton in onClick and then write to the file again?